# Consistent very low (<0.5) AUC preformance of pipeline, cannot explain why

Tags: classification, cross-validation, auc

I have a 2-step ML pipeline (classification, binary, balanced dataset, about 300 samples and tens of thousands of features): step one I train 7 algorithms (XGB, SVM etc.) and step two I train a RFC on these predictions. I do that with 5x5 nested cross-validation, without repeat.

Now, I have 23 different targets (0/1 labels) to predict, so I build 23 independent models. It turns out that some of these models have performances above 0.9 AUC, some are lower, some are close to 0.5, and one of them has a AUC of 0.29. Consistent across multiple runs with different subparts of the dataset, so a bug is excluded.

[image: no, it's not upside-down...]

I don't get how that is possible. The pipeline is the same for all targets so I am sure I do not invert labels or mix up samples, as it works very well for some targets. How can a model be consistently doing exactly the opposite than it is supposed to do?

Comment: Are the 23 labels related in some way?  Is the 5x5 nested CV set up with inner CV building the base-model predictions on out-of-fold, then the RFC training on those and having its performance tested on the outer test fold?  Are the ROC/AUC averaged across outer folds, or using the aggregated predictions?  How do training AUCs look?

Comment: There are 5 outer folds. So with each time 80% of the data, I do 5 inner folds, training on 64% and making base predictions on 16%. Now I have 80% with labels and base predictions. I train a RF on that and generate final predictions for the 20%. Rinse and repeat 4 more times.